# PHPUnit tests failing after adding a ViewServiceProvider for sharing data to views

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am relatively new to testing so please forgive me if this a stupid question.

All my tests are failing after I added a ViewServiceProvider to share data with the views.

The error is:
`Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: policies (SQL: select "name", "slug" from "policies")`

My tests are making use the the refresh database trait:

```php
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    ...
}
```

Here is an example of the ViewServiceProvider:

```php
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\Policy;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void{...}

    public function boot(): void
    {
        view()->share('policies', Policy::all(['name', 'slug']));
    }
}
```

Every works when browsing the site on front end. Am i missing something? Why are the tests failing?

I will appreciate suggestions on how to make the tests pass.

**Edit**
It makes total sense what @Donkarnash said but it's also confusing because according to the docs:

> So, what if we need to register a view composer within our service provider? This should be done within the boot method. This method is called after all other service providers have been registered, meaning you have access to all other services that have been registered by the framework

See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/providers#the-boot-method

Comment: Service Provider is booted before the migrations are run hence it cannot find the table policies

Comment: Thanks @Donkarnash, any idea how one would go about making the tests pass?

Comment: I think I had a similar situation sometime back and I used a dirty hack of caching. It's kind of brittle but it worked.

Comment: What if you wrap the code in if (! app()->runningInConsole()) { view()->share('policies', Policy::all(['name', 'slug'])); }; if it works i write up an answer

Comment: Yeah, i tried something similar @mrhn but then `Undefined variable` exceptions occur. I guess I can add `isset` checks for the variables in the views but i don't want to do that just to make my tests pass. I am passing more than just the policies to the views. But if there is really no other way then i will have to do it.

Comment: Did you try caching the query results in a variable $policies? Changing or setting up conditionals like isset is I feel more untidy than caching. Something like `$policies = Cache::remember('allPolicies', 60, fn() => Policy::all(['name', 'slug']));` followed by view()->share('policies', $policies);

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I found the solutions and posted it. Out of curiosity @Donkarnash, won't the CI/CD tests fail with the caching suggestion? The cache isn't committed to the repo, is it?

Comment: Yes probably it will

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Creating a view composer solved the problem.

```php
namespace App\Http\View\Composers;

use App\Models\Policy;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class PolicyComposer
{
    public function compose(View $view): void
    {
        $view->with('policies', Policy::all(['name', 'slug']));
    }
}
```

Then I referenced the composer in the ViewServiceProvider

```php
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\Policy;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void{...}

    public function boot(): void
    {
        view()->composer('*', PolicyComposer::class);
    }
}
```